# Retrieve ID column of new insert from SQL Server and display in textbox field using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, textbox

I am building my insert new record window called "Add New Case' form in C# and the database is in SQL Server 2019.

Please check the screenshot, I want to display the new record ID in the textbox on the form.

- My textbox name is: `txtVictimID`
- Table name: `Victim`
- Column name: `victim_ID`

**This is how I did it:**
I used the following query : "SELECT max(victim_ID) FROM [GBV_CMS].[dbo].[Victim]"

And once i got the latest ID, i stored it to a variable 'vID' than I added the code:

victim_IDTextBox.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(vID) + 1).ToString();

It works now, but please let me know if my solution is right, or if someone has a better solution to avoid future issues.

And as you can see in the screenshot:

[image]

in the same window form, I need to insert additional case details, which is a separate table in SQL Server.

**How do I make sure, I use the correct`victim_ID` value from the `Victim` table in the `Case` table as a foreign key so it is linked???

For the witness/perpetrator details table, it is 1-N relationship with the Victim table so I need to use the same new value of `victim_ID` in these two tables.**

I was really not able to find a solution to this online, therefore, I am seeking help here.

Appreciate, if anyone could please help with the code and instructions.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You want to save and then show the generated ID on the textbox. What does your saving routine look like?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I want to show the ID that will be generated before I click save.

Comment: Hi Andrei, just edited my question, and added what i tried so far, it seems to work now but I need to make sure, this is the right way to do it and want to know how I add multiple witnesses or perpetrator details for each victim.

Comment: Wrong way round. Use an `IDENTITY` column, then when you insert, don't insert that column at all. Return the new ID value with `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` If you want to insert into other tables, store the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in an SQL variable and do the inserts in the same batch. Or you can return the ID back to C# and pass it back again for the other inserts

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you so much. I have already used IDENTITY column for the table. But, how do I retrieve the ID and display it in the textbox field? Can you please help write the example code that I can replicate?

Comment: As I said, the **immediate** statement after the insert **within the same batch or procedure**, you put something like `DECLARE @newID int = SCOPE_IDENTITY();` then you can do further inserts with that, or you can do `SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS int);` to get it directly back to the client app.

Comment: @Charlieface  - I just used this, and it didnt work:

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() FROM [GBV_CMS].[dbo].[Case]

Comment: No `FROM table` just the function. Like this `INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(whatever...); SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS int);` C# side you receive it with `ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: Many thanks @Charlieface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link helps

[Retrieving Identity or Autonumber Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-identity-or-autonumber-values)